# ¿Qué significa en Argentina "al pedo"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, modismos, argentina

He escuchado y leído a argentinos decir "al pedo", por ejemplo, "estoy al pedo". Es evidente que NO se refiere a "estar pedo", que significa "estar borracho" en algunos sitios.

¿Qué significa "estar al pedo" y en qué contexto se usa? ¿Es algo normal o hay que tener cuidado con quién usarlo? ¿Se usa también en otros países del entorno como en Chile o Uruguay, o es solo en Argentina, o incluso es algo localizado del Río de la Plata/Buenos Aires?

Comment: Nunca la he escuchado en Chile.

Comment: jaja nunca pense que esa frase llamara tanto la atencion , yo ahora estoy al pedo y no sabia que hacer y cai aca :p

Comment: Emn Chile no se usa esa frase.

Comment: "Al Pedo" significa que esta/s aburrido por eso yo soy Argentino

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"Estar al pedo" significa no tener nada que hacer, no cumplir ninguna función.

Es una expresión bastante común en Argentina, aunque más bien ordinaria. Nadie se va a espantar por oirla, pero no es la clase de lenguaje que uno usaría en una entrevista de trabajo, por ejemplo.

Una frase común es "estar más al pedo que bocina de avión" (o "estar más al pedo que cenicero de moto", y hay varias más). Acá la expresión está usada en el sentido de no tener ninguna utilidad.

Otro ejemplo: "Estaba tan al pedo que me puse a hacer un crucigrama". Acá la idea es que no tenía nada (mejor) que hacer; y también se da a entender algo de aburrimiento o hastío.

Comment: Confirmo que de esta misma forma se usa en Uruguay.

Comment: en Mexico ' estar al pedo' , se usa para , 'estar atento' ,, y no como en uruguay o argentina.

Comment: My Mexican friends tell me "no hay pedo" stands for "relax" or "no worries" as in "no one farted". Google translate also confirms that "pedo" means fart.

Answer (score 21):

Transcurría un plácido almuerzo, cuando de pronto, la ilustre visita de una extranjera de intercambio, en un castellano con neto acento canadiense preguntó inocentemente: Pero… para ustedes los argentinos… ¿todo es pedo?

- ¿Como…?
- Sí, claro… Es que hay cosas que todavía no entiendo del todo…
- ¿Por ejemplo?
- Hoy Agustín fue caminando hasta el centro a cambiar una remera y el negocio estaba cerrado. Cuando volvió dijo: “Me hicieron ir al pedo”.
- Claro, eso significa que fue en vano, inútilmente.
- Sí, sí; pero en plural es diferente. Cuando el otro día vinimos en taxi, al bajar Micaela dijo: “Este tachero nos trajo a los pedos”.
- Eso quiere decir que venían muy rápido…
- Sí, ya me di cuenta. Pero me resulta difícil entender la diferencia del singular al plural… Además… hay otras frases que no son lo mismo, por ejemplo: Estar “en” pedo, que estar “al” pedo.
- Claro, estar “en” pedo, es estar borracho; estar “al” pedo, es estar sin hacer nada…
- ¡Eso! ¡eso!, suena parecido a ir “al pedo”… Pero… también lo usan cuando quieren significar negativa a hacer algo…
- A veces, en ese caso decimos: “No voy a ir ni en pedo”, que significa que de ninguna manera lo haremos, o sea… ni borracho iría, ¿me entendés?
- Si, ahora sí. Aunque todavía me queda otra; cuando el otro día Agustín no puso la mesa y vos te enojaste, Agustín luego me contó que vos lo habías “cagado a pedos”…
- Sí, en ese caso quiere decir que lo reté, que le llamé la atención…
- Ahora entiendo un poco más… pero… me acordé de otra: Cuando fuimos al partido de fútbol y el delantero hizo un gol de taquito, el comentario de Agustín fue: “Le salió de pedo”…
- Eso significa que lo hizo por pura suerte, que fue de casualidad… ¿entendés?
- Si, ehmm… Una última pregunta… ¿que quieren decir cuando Micaela le dice a Agustín: “Sucio de miehrda … ¿¿¿¡¡¡Que pedo que te tiraste!!!???…”

Comment: Vaya, gracias, no sabía que "pedo" se usara en tantas expresiones en Argentina. Con respecto a "estar en pedo", en España decimos "estar pedo" o "llevar un pedo".

Comment: @JoulSauron "tener un pedo" is the same here

Comment: +1 porque siendo Argentino no había notado que somos tan geniales para hablar mal. Bueno, un poquito me había dado cuenta, pero medio de pedo :)

Answer (score 4):

Hablando de México, curiosamente, estar **"al pedo"** quiere decir estar "muy bien", estar en un estado "excelente"...o bien, se usa para calificar alguna situación en donde has salido de una manera muy favorable o conveniente.

-"Eh güey, te entregaron la mercancía que estabas esperando?"

-"Sí! y además, me entregaron otro lote que estaba pendiente - al puro pedo!"

-"Sí...al pedo!"

---

- "Y tú? cómo has estado?"
- "Yo ando al pedo...chingón.".

Answer (score 2):

En Argentina, una persona está "al pedo" cuando no está haciendo nada - nada útil o interesante.

> "estoy al pedo" = "no estoy haciendo nada" = "I'm doing nothing"

También se usa mucho la expresión para acciones: una acción "es al pedo" cuando es inútil o en vano. Se usa también, aisladamente, como una exclamación proverbial: "Es al pedo" = "Es inútil" = "It's useless"  (¿qué es inútil? todo, o nada en particular).

Con respecto a "estar borracho", cambia la preposición: "estar **en** pedo" = "to be drunk" ; o "ponerse en pedo" = "emborracharse" = "to get drunk".

En todos los casos, son expresiones muy comunes pero algo vulgares o malsonantes, de esas que conviene entender pero que un extranjero no debería arriesgarse a usar. Algunos eufemismos son "al pepe" o "al cuete (=al cohete)". Una expresión sinónima (desconozco el origen) es "al divino botón".

Comment: En Uruguay tenemos "de pedo" y "ni en pedo" ( de pedo no te caistes! | ni en pedo voy a tu casa !)

Comment: @user983248: the correct form is *eructo*. Besides, I find your comment rather disconnected from the answer.

Comment: En España usamos "estar pedo" (sin preposición) para decir "estar borracho". Igualmente decimos "ponerse pedo", "cogerse un pedo". También se puede usar como "ni pedo": "eso no lo hago ni pedo (ni borracho)".